# Error on execute set_endpoint for WePay

Tags: javascript, wepay

Working through: https://www.wepay.com/developer/process_payments/tokenization-custom-checkout

When I execute:

```
WePay.set_endpoint("stage");
```

I get the error returned:

> messenger:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'wepay_call_path' of null

I have loaded their [tokenization API](https://static.wepay.com/min/js/tokenization.v2.js) and everything seems correct.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wepay but your question may be missing some code. Is this the beginning of the code or are there relevant commands before?

Comment: Thanks @RoyFalk.  I added more context.

Comment: Upvoted the question. Hopefully, someone who knows the answer will come along. MY javascript is worse than my latin...

Comment: Interesting.  Have been going back and forth with their help staff and it turns out that they have the exact same error popping up on their example page.  Will post an answer if there is one.  They may just fix an internal problem and the whole thing goes away.